# Getting first n characters from a file

Tags: command-line, cut

I want to get the first 20 or so characters from a number of files.

I've seen examples using cut but they all seem to get the first 20 characters of each line in the file, while I only want the first characters in the file itself (ie. from the first line), nothing more.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: The `-c` switch in `head` assumes 1 byte = 1 character.

Comment: Note that the `-c` option is a non-portable extension.

Comment: head -c worked on cygwin & centos. head -c brilliant when you need glimpse the contents of say an xml file with no linefeeds

Comment: I do not think this should be marked a duplicate, as the OP did not ask that `cat` (or even `cut`) be the tool used. OP simply noted that they had seen examples using `cut`.

Answer (score 54):

Complete command would be:

```bsh
head -c 20 yourFile.txt
```

Comment: This specifies `20` bytes. Not `20` characters. If you have to handle multibyte characters, use `gawk '{ print substr($1, 1, 20); }' < yourFile.txt` or `python3 -c 'print(input()[:20])' < yourFile.txt` for example.

Answer (score 7):

Didn't realize the -c option for `head` was non portable. You can use `dd` to output the first 20 bytes like so:

```
dd if=/path/to/infile of=/path/to/outfile  bs=20 count=1
```

You can omit the `of=/path/to/outfile` part if you want your result to stdout.