# Cut off pipe after N bytes

Tags: bash, pipe, pv

I am piping information to a file using `myTool > file.txt 2>&1`, but the tool might generate GigaBytes worth of data - I need to cut off after the first N bytes, let say 2MB.
It seems `pv` can not do that, and sadly it is not an option to go by lines (`head`).

Is there no basic tool to do this?

Ideally, it would work like this: `myTool | limiter --amount 2M > file.txt 2>&1`.

Comment: usually `head` can do bytes, too - which flavor are you using?

Comment: @frostschutz
It seems I simply overlooked this! Coreutils 8.32. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it - thank you for pointing out the (seemingly) obvious!

Comment: @cyrus, I can't comment on your answer: couldn't you just switch the numbers? `dd bs=2M count=1`?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346367/getting-first-n-characters-from-a-file

Answer (score 1):

Several implementations of `head` support a `-c` option for that. The GNU implementation also accepts suffixes, `M` for mebibytes, recent versions also supporting `MB` for megabyte (1,000,000) and `MiB` for mebibyte (1,048,576).

```
head -c 2097152
head -c 2M
head -c 2MiB
```

```
head -c 2000000
head -c 2MB
```

With `pv`, you can specify the size with `-s` and tell it to stop reading as soon as it's reached with `-S`. Again, suffixes are supported, but that's for powers of 1024, not 1000.

```
pv -Ss 2M
pv -Ss 2097152
```

```
pv -Ss 2000000
```

(add `-q` if you don't want progress information)

With GNU `dd`, you can do:

```
dd iflag=fullblock,count_bytes bs=64k count=2097152 status=none
dd iflag=fullblock,count_bytes bs=64k count=2MiB status=none
dd iflag=fullblock,count_bytes bs=64k count=2M status=none
```

```
dd iflag=fullblock,count_bytes bs=64k count=2000000 status=none
dd iflag=fullblock,count_bytes bs=64k count=2MB status=none
```

Comment: A question about `dd`: when `count` does not have a suffix, isn't that counting 2,000,000 64k blocks (131,072,000,000 bytes)?

Comment: @glennjackman, with the `count_bytes` `iflag`, the `count` is in bytes.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that in my dd man page.